# Forms in salesforce site.com

Tags: site.com

I have created new site from site.com in my org. Now i want to add new form to site page, but while adding form it is not showing any object to select in dropdownlist. I have provided read and create permission to guest user but it is not working yet.

Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Can you show some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Rahul - I see you have tagged the question with Visualforce.  Is this really a Visualforce Force.com Site or is it actually a Site.com site?  It sounds like it is really a Site.com site, which would mean no Visualforce.

Comment: First i was searching for salesforce.com tag and it was not there so i posted it in visualforce tags. But now i got this site.com tags so i have changed the tag.

Comment: @RahulNagardalekar - Thanks for updating it!  I was going to but wasn't 100% certain you really meant Site.com. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you set the create permission for the object in the guest user's profile, you have to then click the Refresh the Picklist link to see the Object in the list.

[image]

If you've done that, are you 100% certain that you have given the Create permission to the correct object and correct profile?

Even if your own profile has no permissions to the object, you can still add it as a form if the Site's Guest User profile has the create permission.